# YouTube iframe API allownetworking=internal

Tags: api, cordova, iframe, youtube

I'm including YouTube videos in an iPad app (cordova).

For the nodewebkit desktop version, I could easily disable clicking through the video to youtube (and therefore being stuck there with no way to get back to the app) by adding allownetworking="internal" to the object embed code.

However, flash does not work on the iPad & this attribute seems to be ignored for the iframe API. What are my options? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you hook into events within the iframe and detect navigation away from your embedded video?

Comment: I figured this out, finally. Although, it is not as good of a solution as allownetworking="internal" was in the flash embedded object. When creating your player object, add the parameters     playerVars: {  'modestbranding':1,  'showinfo':0, 'autohide':1 },

Comment: ^^^ After further testing, this option is not acceptable, as the youtube logo will sometimes appear watermarked on the video & allow click-through. As well as any clickable areas created by the content creator.

Comment: If you want full control, host the videos yourself. YouTube has a vested interest in having their player take you to YouTube at times.

Comment: I have a client that wants to include youtube video playlists in their iPad app. These playlists already exist and some of them have 50+ videos in them. They want to be able to add videos to this playlist and have them appear in the app. Hosting them myself is not an option. Its strange to me that this is possible in flash but not HTML5

Comment: It was possible in Flash because it's a built-in part of Flash's embed tags, whereas it doesn't exist in HTML5. YouTube has no incentive to emulate the feature in the HTML5 player.